# Java Swing блокировка ProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, jdialog

Давно не использовал свинг, а сейчас есть необходимость, при этом возникла одна проблема...
Есть 3 класса (код упрощен исключительно для воспроизведения проблемы)

```
public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8355213641156143287L;

    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("MY FRAME");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void start() {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            TestFrame testFrame = new TestFrame();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {System.out.println(ex);
            }
            testFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}


import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

public class WaitingDialog implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true); 
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setString("Wait...");

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setSize(200, 50);
        dialog.add(progressBar);
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread(new WaitingDialog()).start();
        TestFrame.start();    

    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что прогресс бар диалога первого класса должен отрисовываться до запуска фрейма. В классе фрейма вызван `Thread.sleep(5000)`, при выполнении которого прогресс бар виснет. В реальности, разумеется, никакого `Thread.sleep(5000)` , это для воспроизведения проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Любые компоненты Swing работают исключительно из одного потока, потока рассылки своих событий (EventDispatchThread). Трогать и менять состояние компонентов Swing из других потоков нельзя.

`new Thread(new WaitingDialog()).start();`

этот код приведет к ошибкам.

Более того, нельзя создавать компонентов и окон Swing напрямую даже в методе `main()`, только через `invokeLater()`

Вашу программу можно переписать так:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    // открывает диалог.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new WaitingDialog().run());
    // таймер в отдельном потоке ждет 5 секунд.
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // открываем окно - тоже из потока событий Swing
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TestFrame().setVisible(true));
      }
    }, 5*1000);

}
```

Сначала откроется progress bar, потом когда истечет 5 секунд (для примера, в реальной программе что-то сработает), открывается окно - тоже обязательно в  Event Dispatch Thread.